# Js-interop pub install fail

Tags: javascript, interop, dart

I can't install the js-interop via pub. I tried to create a new projet to see if the problem is with my actual project, but it didn't work in the new project either.

Here is how my pubspec.yaml looks like:

```
name:  Test
description:  A sample application

dependencies:
  js: { hosted: js }
```

When I try to run "Pub install" from the Dart's editors menu, I receive this message:

```
Running pub install ...
Pub install fail, Resolving dependencies...
Package "unittest" doesn't have a pubspec.yaml file.
```

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: This issue was fixed [here](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per John Evans' comments in the previous answer, it's very likely because there's a bug in pub right now that affects Windows users. See: dartbug.com/6513

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's how I got js-interop to work:

Create a new app (I called mine interoper)

Add the dependecy to pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
    js: 0.0.9
```

Run `pub install`

Import the package in my interoper.dart file:

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';
```

You can see the instructions on http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js

Now, I did run into one problem: the editor complained that it could not find the package. I think this is a bug in the editor: when I closed the file and then reopened it, the problem went away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives me the same error when I try to run pub install.

Comment: Just so I am clear: when you create a brand new app and then follow the steps I outline, do you still have a problem? Also, is your Dart Editor current?

Comment: Are you working from windows?  If so there is a bug with pub right now: http://www.dartbug.com/6513

Comment: I tried pub update, didn't work. @JohnEvans maybe it is that, I'll star that issue.